# Sed regexp /d deleting whole file

Tags: bash, regex, sed, known-hosts

Given a typical known_hosts file:

```
[123.45.67.89]:22 ssh-rsa bbuivvhbkbjdnflksndkfnksnfk...
[98.76.54.32]:14444 ssh-rsa hohdibsodbfoasbfbsabdfbsd...
[77.34.122.33]:32209 ssh-rsa bksdjncknsdbcksbdcbhdhhb...
```

Not knowing the line# in the file, but knowing the ip address.

---

The following deletes all lines in the file:

```
sed '/98\.76\.54\.32/d known_hosts > known_hosts'
```

I'm hoping that I'm just missing something absurdly simple.

Testing my regex [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2tj1c) gives me the match I need, and my impression is that:

```
sed '/pattern/d'  file > file
```

Should drop just the first line where the */pattern/* is a match.

---

I know I'm no regex guru nor bash master, but I seriously thought this was not going to be a several search, two coffee battle.  Can anyone throw me a bone?

---

EDIT: 4 answers in minutes and all right.  I knew it was something ridiculous.  Hopefully my folly shows up in someone else's searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `-i` option of `sed` (edit files in place):

```
sed -i '/98\.76\.54\.32/d' known_hosts
```

If you do an output redirection as you did you *immediately* empty the file (before its content is read by `sed`). If you want to use redirection you have to use a temporary output file:

```
sed '/98\.76\.54\.32/d' known_hosts > known_hosts.tmp
mv known_hosts.tmp known_hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sed, use `ssh-keygen -R 98.76.54.32`

> -R hostname
>   Removes all keys belonging to hostname from a known_hosts file. This option is useful to delete hashed hosts (see the -H option above)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, redirecting your output onto your input file is working against you here, as the output gets opened for write and truncated before the shell actually launches `sed`. You'll need to write to a temporary file, or use the `-i` option of `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `>` output redirection that is emptying the file. This is because the output file is opened before the input file. Use `sed -i` to do an in place edit

```
sed -i '/98\.76\.54\.32/d known_hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

I sympathise, regex is not my friend. The `>` is overwriting the file. `sed -i '/TO DELETE/ d' file.txt` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'g/98\.76\.54\.32/d' -cx known_hosts
```

1. `g` global search
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close